# Save session data in Phonegap for Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, session, cookies

I have a pretty basic Phonegap wrapper for a Rails web app. The Rails app uses cookies to find and save the current user (no Devise). Phonegap can't use traditional cookies for some dumb reason. Does anyone know how I can save session data in the Phonegap app, either with local storage or something else, that my SessionHelper Rails module can then use to retrieve and save the current user, and do so without interfering with how it works on a normal browser? My current user method is below:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: cookies.signed[:auth_token]) if cookies.signed[:auth_token]
end
```

Comment: Why do you say phonegap can't use cookies? I've been using phonegap + JEE session cookies with no problem for a a long time and never had anything special to do.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't save the cookies when I close the app. So I need it so that a user can close the app and then reopen it without having to sign back in.

Comment: Curious if you've figured out how to solve this yet?

Comment: No that was never resolved. I had to abandon Phonegap as a result.